# How to push feature branch in gerrit

Tags: git, github, gerrit

While working with Gerrit, I created a new feature branch from master locally and then pushed it to the remote repository. That part works fine and the new branch can be seen on the remote.

But when I commit to that feature branch and try to push it, all my changes go to master branch. I don't understand why?

I double checked my location by running
`git branch` (it is pointing to my feature branch)

Please explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch` is not enough: try and check the output of `git branch -avv` to see local and remote tracking branches.

Combine that with `git status`, to check which branch you are currently using.

Then you can make sure:

- you actually are using feature branch
- feature branch is indeed linked to an upstream branch.

But in the case of Gerrit, make sure to push using the right URL: see [Gerrit push](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#_git_push).

Comment: Thanks a lot. its working as I mentioned full address on push. :)

Comment: addition to last question I am facing one more issue. So now changes are pushed to gerrit and they are visible for review. But what I want here is, 2 different person will be working on this feature branch and they will be pulling changes to each other to completed feature. But when someone is trying to clone/pull my feature branch my commit is not visible to them. how these changes will be visible which is in review state in gerrit.

Comment: @StillLearning You might consider pushing to two different remotes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309): one being Gerrit, the other a repository from which you can both exchange commits.

Comment: I guess no, there is no push for 2 different locations. Let me ask question again. 
So as I mentioned, I am successfully able to push my changes to Gerrit feature branch with 1 test commit. this change is visible on Gerrit web and its not merged yet.
Now another developer pulled this feature branch locally and I was expecting that my unmerged changes should be pulled into his local machine. But its not like. this.

Comment: @StillLearning "I guess no, there is no push for 2 different locations": exactly: make a second one. Does the developer pull the branch from the Gerrit repository?

Comment: @StillLearning Gerrit will store patches to be reviewed in their own namespace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372991/6309. Your developer might need to adlust its refspecs.

Comment: Its working now,  as mentioned in Download section, command can be easily found. thanks a ton for this help. It saved my whole day.

Comment: @StillLearning Perfect, well done!